# How to retrive keys by comparing values of map list from config in scala

Tags: scala

Let say I have a config file with the following:

```
modules :{
    "google" : ["101","201","501"],
    "fb" : ["201"],
    "yahoo" : ["101", "104","110"],
    "aws" : ["104", "110"]
}
```

I would like to retrieve list of keys (e.g [google,fb] for 201 value) by comparing the values associated with the keys.

e.g.

1. If I pass 201 as value then it should return `[google,fb]`
2. If I pass 101 as value then it should return `[google,yahoo]`
3. If I pass 104 as value then it should return `[yahoo,aws]`
4. If I pass 501 as value then it should return `[google]`
5. If I pass 300 as value then it should return emptylist `[]`

Using the following code I am able to read maplist but not able to iterate and get the keys list.

```
val modules = configs.getObject("modules").asScala
println("modules : "+ modules)
optional_modules.foreach( x => println(x._1,  x._2.unwrapped) )

Ouput of above codebase : 
modules Map(aws -> SimpleConfigList(["104","110"]), yahoo -> SimpleConfigList(["101","104","110"]), fb -> SimpleConfigList(["201"]), google -> SimpleConfigList(["101","201","501"]))

(aws,[104, 110])
(yahoo,[101, 104, 110])
(fb,[201])
(google,[101, 201, 501])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Config` into some normal type e.g. normal `Map` and then use standard operations:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
val cfgObj = configs.getObject("modules")
val cfg = cfgObj.toConfig
val keys = cfgObj.keySet().asScala
val statuses: Map[String, List[String]] =
  keys.map { key =>
    key -> cfg.getStringList(key).asScala.toList
  }.toMap

def find(status: String) = statuses.flatMap {
  case (site, list) if list.contains(status) => List(site)
  case _                                     => List.empty 
}
```

If you are doing a lot of things like that I suggest using pureconfig instead:

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

case class Statuses(modules: Map[String, List[String]]) {

  def find(status: String) = statuses.flatMap {
    case (site, list) if list.contains(status) => List(site)
    case _                                     => List.empty 
  }
}

val statuses = ConfigSource.fromConfig(configs).load[Statuses]

statuses.find("google")
```